# How to remove whitespace from a string in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Here's my example:

```
hash = {"buy"=>"Buy ", "quantity"=>"3 ", "get"=>"Get ", "reward"=>"1 ", "free"=>"Free"}

def stripit(value)
  #value.gsub!('B', 'C')
  value.gsub!('/\s+/', '')
  value
end

newhash = hash.update(hash){|key,value| stripit(value)}
puts newhash.inspect
```

`gsub` works on the value -- the first commented replacement works -- but for some reason it is not removing whitespace.

How can I remove whitespaces from a hash value?

Comment: You may consider using the ```strip!``` method instead. Saves having a function typed out.

Comment: Do you want to remove any whitespace, or just the ones at the start and end of your values?

Comment: I want to remove any whitespace

Comment: All three methods below work.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to incorporate your comment. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments. Perhaps just change the title to "Remove all whitespace from all hash values that are strings". You don't need "Ruby" in the title because of the Ruby tag.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `each` method with `strip!` to modify hash values.

```
hash = {"buy"=>"Buy ", "quantity"=>"3 ", "get"=>"Get ", "reward"=>"1 ", "free"=>"Free"}

hash.each_value(&:strip!)

p hash
# => {"buy"=>"Buy", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1", "free"=>"Free"}
```

Comment: If you don't use the result of `map`, you should use `each`.

Comment: Not working for me. I've tried on two different systems (OSX and Ubuntu) and different versions of ruby.

Comment: You should use `Hash#each_value` here.

Comment: Still not working. I think the problem here is with strip, not with the method of iterating over the hash.

Comment: @LukasBaliak : the OP wants to replace every whitespace, not just strip the String.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that you've wrapped your regex in quotation marks, so it's not matching the way you expect!

`value.gsub!(/\s+/, '')`

---

(Edit: complete code, copies original question's code but alters the gsub! argument. Tested with ruby 2.3.1)

```
hash = {"buy"=>"Buy ", "quantity"=>"3 ", "get"=>"Get ", "reward"=>"1 ", "free"=>"Free"}

def stripit(value)
  value.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
  value
end

newhash = hash.update(hash){|key,value| stripit(value)}
puts newhash.inspect
```

Output:

```
{"buy"=>"Buy", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1", "free"=>"Free"}
```

Comment: Not working for me on multiple versions of Ruby on multiple architectures.

Comment: What are you using? I used your example and this worked for me on OS X, ruby 2.3.1

Comment: I just tried it with CentOS, ruby 2.3.0 and it works there, also.

Comment: It works on a string by itself but for some reason not a hash value. FYI: Ubuntu 2.3.1.

Comment: @jdussault: You might want to write the complete code you're running, this might clear the confusion.

Comment: My apologies. I failed to notice the line `value` in the asker's code. I removed my comment and also will edit my answer, where I also got it wrong.

Comment: No worries!  Probably good to get me to post the whole excerpt, anyway.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a new_hash and not modify the original one :

```
new_hash = hash.map{|k,v| [k,v.gsub(/\s+/,'')]}.to_h
```

With Rails or ActiveSupport [extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), it becomes even shorter:

```
hash.transform_values{|v| v.gsub(/\s+/,'')}
```

NOTE: It removes any whitespace in the values. `"Get A "` will be converted to `"GetA"`. `String#strip` would just convert it to `"Get A"`

Comment: It doesn't require Rails, only [Active Support's core extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). See Section 11.5.1. The core extensions allow us to cherry-pick small sections from Active Support as needed.

Comment: Note the asker's comment on the question. It may be just me, but I view the technique of converting a hash to an array, operating on the array and then converting the array back to hash as brutish, particularly when, as here, there are simple ways to operate on the hash directly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. I totally agree it's suboptimal. Is there an alternative without mutation, with short and clear syntax and without the need to require anything?

Comment: Sure. The asker can just replace `value.gsub!('/\s+/', '')` with `value.gsub('/\s+/', '')` (which is required anyway) and `update` with `merge`. Another way is `hash.keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] =...}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's totally subjective, but they don't look short and clear to me, especially not `hash.update(hash) { |_,v,_|`. `transform_values` should be in standard Ruby. BTW, fruity tells me that all our methods have similar performance, so converting to_a and back to_h doesn't seem so bad, even though it's still kinda ugly.

Comment: I added the other way I mentioned to my answer. I recall that when I first saw `hash.merge(hash) { |v,o,n| ... }` I was both mystified and intrigued. Now it's as familiar as `map`.

Comment: Sure, it's very powerful, but it's too much boilerplate code for our purpose : just changing the values. A more complex syntax than `transform_values` is neither needed nor desired.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Finally, both `merge` and `update` must look for duplicate keys (between `hash` and `hash`!) before calculating the new values! Isn't that brutish?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the line `value` in `stripit` if you replace `v.gsub!(/\s+/, '')` (or just `/\s/`) with `v.gsub(/\s/, '')`. That's permitted (and preferred, imo, for better readability and saving a line of code), because [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) is handling the in-place replacement. (Readers: the asker has that line `value` because [String#gsub!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` when no change is made.

You may want confirm the hash value is a string before attempting the substitution (unless you are certain that, even in future, there will never be a value that is not a string, but even then, it does no harm to check).

I suggest the following.

```
hash = {"buy"=>"Buy It ", "quantity"=>"3 ", "get"=>"Get ", "reward"=>"1 ",
        "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=> 42 }
```

if `hash` is not to be mutated:

```
hash.merge(hash) { |_,v,_| v.is_a?(String) ? v.gsub(/\s/, '') : v }
  #=> {"buy"=>"BuyIt", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1", "free"=>"Free"} 
hash
  #=> {"buy"=>"Buy It ", "quantity"=>"3 ", "get"=>"Get ", "reward"=>"1 ",
  #    "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=>42}
```

if `hash` is to be mutated:

```
hash.update(hash) { |_,v,_| v.is_a?(String) ? v.gsub(/\s/, '') : v }
  #=> {"buy"=>"BuyIt", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1",   
  #    "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=>42} 
hash
  #=> {"buy"=>"BuyIt", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1",
  #    "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=>42}
```

This uses the forms of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) and `Hash#update` that employ a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here that is of course all keys. See the docs for details, particularly the meanings of the three block variables. (I've represented two of the three block variables with underscores to indicate they are not used in the block calculation.)

**Another way**

If `hash` is not to be mutated:

```
hash.keys.each_with_object({}) do |k,h|
  v = hash[k]
  h[k] = v.is_a?(String) ? v.gsub(/\s/, '') : v
end
  #=> {"buy"=>"BuyIt", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1",
  # "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=>42} 

hash
  #=> {"buy"=>"Buy It ", "quantity"=>"3 ", "get"=>"Get ", "reward"=>"1 ",
  #    "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=>42}
```

If `hash` is to be mutated:

```
hash.keys.each do |k|
  v = hash[k]
  hash[k] = v.is_a?(String) ? v.gsub(/\s/, '') : v
end
  #=> ["buy", "quantity", "get", "reward", "free", "THE answer"]
hash
  #=> {"buy"=>"BuyIt", "quantity"=>"3", "get"=>"Get", "reward"=>"1",
  #    "free"=>"Free", "THE answer"=>42}
```

Note that in this last case `hash` is mutated but the block does not return the updated `hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map` with a *bang* operator of you want, like this:

```
hash.values.map! {|value| value.strip!}
```